# IONIC 2 images display on browser , but not on android device

Tags: image, angular, path, ionic2

[image]

It's a path issue , I'm in welcome.ts and reference to the image by this path "../../assets/img/splash/1.png"

--it works well on the browser - but not work on my Android device

how to solve this issue ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `"assets/img/splash/1.jpg"` instead. Ionic will put the correct address for each platform.

Comment: Worked well , thanq